# New Hire Original Department Name from monthly Active Employees List- SQL

Tags: sql

I need to pull new hires per department from active employees list. when running the enclosed query:

- using employeeID condition, I get original department which is correct
- using DepartmentName as condition, I see Employee 3 showing as a new hire in both Finance and Marketing Department. which is wrong as Marketing is the employee new department.
  Can you please help me modifying the query so employeeID 3 shows as new hire in Finance only.or may be add a new column for original Department name.

Thank you

```
EmployeeID       Department    OrganizationStartDate       RehireDate    AsOfDate
1                Finance       10/15/2021                  10/15/2021    1/31/2022
2                Finance       11/15/2021                  11/15/2021    1/31/2022
1                Finance       10/15/2021                  10/15/2021    2/28/2022
2                Finance       11/15/2021                  11/15/2021    2/28/2022
3                Finance       2/13/2022                   2/13/2022     2/28/2022
1                Finance       10/15/2021                  10/15/2021    3/31/2022
2                Finance       11/15/2021                  11/15/2021    3/31/2022
3                Finance       2/13/2022                   2/13/2022     3/31/2022
3                Marketing     2/13/2022                   2/13/2022     4/30/2022
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx0mP.png)

```
select 
    Year
    ,Month
    ,HireDate
    ,EmployeeID
    ,DepartmentName
    ,count(EmployeeID) as TotalNumberOfNewHires
from --HireTimes
(
    SELECT 
        year(isnull(RehireDate, OrganizationStartDate)) as Year
        , month(isnull(RehireDate, OrganizationStartDate)) as Month
        , isnull(RehireDate, OrganizationStartDate) as HireDate
        , EmployeeID
        ,DepartmentName
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  EmployeeID, isnull(RehireDate, OrganizationStartDate)
           order by RehireDate, OrganizationStartDate  DESC) AS RID
    FROM   [Employees]
    WHERE isnull(RehireDate, OrganizationStartDate) >  '2022-01-01' 
        --and DepartmentName = 'Finance' -- 'Marketing'
        --and EmployeeID = 3
 ) HireTimes 
where RID = 1
group by 
    year
    ,month
    ,HireDate
    ,EmployeeID
    ,DepartmentName
```

Comment: Why don't you indent your code

Comment: The code is so much easier to read now , which means more people might help you, and it took less than a minute. You'll get a lot further here if you make that basic effort yourself when posting the question.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you so much. I need to show the original/ hiring department though so I used your first query with min(AsOfDate) and it works perfect. For the second technique, I'm trying to find a way to self join when HireDate = AsOfDate to get the very first department for employee 3.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SQL Fiddle with the SQL Server 2017 compatibility mode.  Change code to your RDBMS when playing.

```
-- 1 ~ create tables
create table hr_data
(
  EmployeeID int,
  Department varchar(32),
  StartDate date,
  RehireDate date,
  AsOfDate date
);

-- 2 ~ insert data
insert into hr_data values(1, 'Finance', '10/15/2021', '10/15/2021', '1/31/2022');
insert into hr_data values(2, 'Finance', '11/15/2021', '11/15/2021', '1/31/2022');
insert into hr_data values(1, 'Finance', '10/15/2021', '10/15/2021', '2/28/2022');
insert into hr_data values(2, 'Finance', '11/15/2021', '11/15/2021', '2/28/2022');
insert into hr_data values(3, 'Finance', '2/13/2022', '2/13/2022', '2/28/2022');
insert into hr_data values(1, 'Finance', '10/15/2021', '10/15/2021', '3/31/2022');
insert into hr_data values(2, 'Finance', '11/15/2021', '11/15/2021', '3/31/2022');
insert into hr_data values(3, 'Finance', '2/13/2022', '2/13/2022', '3/31/2022');
insert into hr_data values(3, 'Marketing', '2/13/2022', '2/13/2022', '4/30/2022');
```

The first two steps creates a table and loads data.  I like using effective dating, type two dimensional modeling.  Thus, any end data that is null is the most recent record.

For new hires, you want to look at the most recent records for employees 1, 2, and 3.

```
-- Show most receent record
select 
  a1.*
from
  hr_data a1 
join
  (
  select employeeid, max(asofdate) as asofdate
  from hr_data
  group by employeeid 
  ) 
b1 
on 
  a1.employeeid = b1.employeeid and
  a1.asofdate = b1.asofdate
```

This can be achieved by getting the max (asofdate) for each employee and joining it back to the hr_data table.

[image]

There are really no new hires (2023)!

Here is the link to play with the code.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5908ae/6/0

The real problem is duplicate data.  I re-wrote the query in your style using a row_number function to rank by AsOfDate.  This fixes the problem differently compared to the first query.

```
-- Extract hire year, month, date, employee, dept where rn = 1 (most recent)
select *
from
(
  select 
    YEAR(COALESCE(RehireDate, StartDate)) as HireYear,
    MONTH(COALESCE(RehireDate, StartDate)) as HireMonth,
    COALESCE(RehireDate, StartDate) as HireDate,
    AsOfDate,
    EmployeeID,
    Department,
    row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by AsOfDate Desc) as rn
  from
    hr_data
) as d
where d.rn = 1
```

Again, here is the code to play with.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5908ae/23/0

[image]

Comment: you do know, that changing the output type, you can create markup code to insert as the images are unreadable

Comment: nbk - what are you talking about???  I opened a incognito window, opened this post, and the images look fine.  Enclosed is the code, a link to fiddler to bring up the example and images ...

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you so much. I need to show the original/ hiring department though so I used your first query with min(AsOfDate) and it works perfect. For the second technique, I'm trying to find a way to self join when HireDate = AsOfDate to get the very first department for employee 3.

Comment: You can create two common table expressions.  Rank by date ASC (first) department and Rank by date DESC (last) department.  Then join the two CTEs on employee number to get your answer in one record - first department worked and last (or current) department worked.

Comment: Images CAN be unreadable (as they are for me) this is due to how I am connected and the rules that are applied to that connection (by network admins). Always use text in preference to images. see https://dbfiddle.uk/D1EObRgW